# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserRepositor

Tags: nestjs

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context. Potential solutions: - If UserRepository is a provider, is it part of the current

I'm currently workin in v9 and I have this error, I don't understand why.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/ociel-gonzalez-solis/cv-nestjs-test-portafolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never provide a custom provider to mock the `UserRepository`. Something like

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
            save: jest.fn(),
            find: jest.fn(),
          }
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

You can then tailor the `jest.fn()` methods to your liking as your test needs. [You can find a whole repository of test examples here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)